# How does rails convert ActiveRecord models to JSON? Which source file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm curious how ActiveRecord models convert their objects to json, where in the source would I find this method?

Comment: Here? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON`

Documentation is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: So in controller actions when you render as json, it just calls as_json under the covers?